# How to calculate the likelihood for an element in a route that traverses a probability graph is correct?

Tags: math, probability

I have an asymmetric directed graph with a set of probabilities (so the likelihood that a person will move from point A to B, or point A to C, etc).  Given a route through all the points, I would like to calculate the likelihood that each choice made in the route is a good choice.

As an example, suppose a graph of just 2 points.

```
//In a matrix, the probabilities might look like
//A     B
[ 0    0.9  //A
  0.1   0 ] //B
```

So the probability of moving from A to B is 0.9 and from B to A is 0.1.  Given the route A->B, how correct is the first point (A), and how correct is the second point (B).

Suppose I have a bigger matrix with a route that goes A->B->C->D.  So, some examples of what I would like to know:

- How likely is it that A comes before B,C, & D
- How likely is it that B comes after A
- How likely is it that C & D come after B

Basically, at each point, I want to know the likelihood that the previous points come before the current and also the likelihood that the following points come after.  I don't need something that is statistically sound.  Just an indicator that I can use for relative comparisons. Any ideas?

**update:** I see that this question is not useful to everyone but the answer is really useful to me so I've tried to make the description of the problem more clear and will include my answer shortly in case it helps someone.

Comment: How does probability fit into this problem at all? Can't you tell which state you are at when you are traversing your graph?

Comment: I realize now that I did not phrase this problem correctly at all. TSP has nothing to do with it at this point. I have a route and a graph of probabilities.  I want to find the likelihood that a route is correct based on probabilities.  I'm going to update the question.

Comment: You seem to be alluding to an optimization problem for which you haven't stated the optimization criterion.  Can you state it more explicitly?  For example, right in your first paragraph you say a "good choice" but why is one choice better than another?  How is this measured?

Comment: @ChrisA. Thanks  You helped me clarify the problem.  I updated the problem with another example.  A simple 2 point asymmetric directed graph.

Comment: OK, you're making progress, but still not there: "Given the route A->B, I can probably be 90% certain that A comes before B."  This is still fuzzy and handwaving.  What is the mathematical optimization criterion?  Can you write it down?  I suspect you aren't even sure what it is, hence lots of people not being able to answer your question.

Comment: When I was working on it on my own, I came up with something but it didn't really work that well.  I was thinking I would have a route [A,B,C,D], and then two probability arrays.  One for the probability that the stuff ahead of a point is correct (Pbefore) and another for the probability that the stuff after is correct (Pafter) but not the order that it is correct.  So Pbefore(A) = Pafter(A) = P(A<B and A<C)

Comment: And then I get confused.  Maybe Pbefore(B) (the probability that B comes after the points in front of it) would be P(A<B)*probability that A is correct.  Pbefore(C) might be P(B<C and A<C)....the thing is, it doesn't really matter if the answer is 100% mathematically correct.  It just has to provide some way of comparing the routes through the probabilities to say a point in a route is pretty good.  'Pretty good' might come from doing experiments and monitoring this indicator we are currently defining.

Comment: @ChrisA - I just realized I am really on the wrong track...because is I have a 2 point system, with AB having a prob of 0.51 and BA having a prob of 0.49 then my confidence that A comes before B should be very low, not 0.51.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much thought, I came up with something that suits my needs.  It still has the the same problem where to get an accurate answer would require checking every possible route.  However, in my case, only checking direct and the first indirect routes are enough to give an idea of how "correct" my answer is.

First I need the confidence for each probability.  This is a separate calculation and is contained in a separate matrix (that maps 1 to 1 to the probability matrix).  I just take the 1.0-confidenceInterval for each probability.

If I have a route A->B->C->D, I calculate a "correctness indicator" for a point.  It looks like I am getting some sort of average of a direct route and the first level of indirect routes.

Some examples:

Denote P(A,B) as probability that A comes before B
Denote C(A,B) as confidence in the probability that A comes before B
Denote P`(A,C) as confidence that A comes before C based on the indirect route A->B->C

At point B, likelihood that A comes before it:

indicator = P(A,B)*C(A,B)/C(A,B)

At point C, likelihood that A & B come before:

P`(A,C) = P(A,B)*P(B,C)
C`(A,C) = C(A,B)*C(B,C)

indicator = [P(A,C)*C(A,C) + P(B,C)*C(B,C) + P'(A,C)*C'(A,C)]/[C(A,C)+C(B,C)+C'(A,C)]

So this gives me some sort of indicator that is always between 0 and 1, and takes the first level indirect route into account (from->indirectPoint->to).  It seems to provide the rough estimation I was looking for.  It is not a great answer, but it does provide some estimate and since nothing else provides anything better, it is suitable

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible efficiently. If there was an algorithm to calculate the probability that a point was in the wrong position, you could simply work out which position was least wrong for each point, and thus calculate the correct order. The problem is essentially the same as finding the optimal route.

The subsidiary question is what the probability is 'of', here. Can the probability be 100%? How would you know?

Part of the reason the travelling salesman problem is hard is that there is no way to know that you have the optimal solution except looking at all the solutions and finding that it is the shortest.

Comment: I apologize. I did not correctly frame my problem.  I've updated the question. I just have a graph of probabilities and a route through the graph. That might make things a bit easier.  In terms of if there was an algorithm to calculate the probability of a point being in the wrong position, I don't think you could use it to find the optimal route because improving the probability of a point might lower the probability of another point in a complex graph.

Comment: The other thing I was thinking of is maybe not using probabilities but using something similar (I called it confidence although that is probably a synonym for probability).  But in an asymmetric problem, if the distance from A to B is 9 and the distance from B to A is 1, then I can say with pretty high confidence that A comes before B (I think).  Maybe 90% confident in this case.  If I start throwing in other points, it becomes more complicated

Comment: It sounds like you are assigning probabilities/confidence based on Greedy assumptions. I don't see the value of that. The TSP solution algorithm that follows the general algorithm of computing the point to point probabilities will seem best by that measure, and there is no guarantee that's the case, particularly if you assign probabilities using greedy assumptions.

Comment: hmm...I will have to think about this.  Based on the updated 2 point  example in my question, it makes sense to me to say that AB is better than BA.  And it also seems like AB is way better than BA (it's not like the probabilities for the two routes are 0.49 and 0.51 - there are big differences).  So for the simple example, having a confidence number has a value to me.  I 'think' it should apply to more complex examples...

Answer (score 0):

Replace probability matrix (p) with -log(p) and finding shortest path in that matrix would solve your problem.